# NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Why such structure

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def p(self, b=self.a):
        print b
```

gives an error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Default argument values are evaluated at function define-time, but `self` is an argument only available at function call time. Thus arguments in the argument list cannot refer each other.

It's a common pattern to default an argument to `None` and add a test for that in code:

```
def p(self, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = self.a
    print b
```

**Update 2022:** Python developers are now [considering late-bound argument defaults](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0671/) for future Python versions.

Comment: Although I think that the above is not very pretty (I come from ruby where things just work fine), the above actually works as a workaround. It's still awkward that python chose to make self unavailable in a parameter list.

Comment: @shevy: "self" has no special meaning in python, it's just the name _conventionally_ chosen for the first argument. You can as well replace "self" by "me" or "x".

Comment: Is there no better way to do this?  If we have a function that takes a dozen default arguments that should reference self, do we really need a dozen if statements?  This is terribly awkward.

Comment: If the caller *explicitly* passed in `None` for the second parameter, it gets over-ridden to `self.a`, which is unexpected and surprising.

Answer (score 20):

For cases where you also wish to have the option of setting 'b' to None:

```
def p(self, **kwargs):
    b = kwargs.get('b', self.a)
    print b
```

Answer (score 16):

A `self` `NameError` can also occur if you fail to define self inside a method signature. This error typically will appear as `TypeError`, as there will be a mismatch between expected and given arguments[1]. However, if you accept a variable number of arguments, `self` will be `arg[0]`, and the variable `self` will be undefined.

A minimal example.

```
class Obj:
    def foo(*args):
        print(self.bar)
```

>NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Correction:

```
class Obj:
    def baz(self, *args):
        print(self.bar)
```

[1] http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: This example doesn't make sense in ordinary cases. Omitting a `self` parameter **from a method** will normally result in a `TypeError` complaining about a wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Not necessarily, consider the case where a method should be `foo(self, *args, **kwargs)` but self is omitted.

Comment: Plausible, but uncommon, and certainly doesn't match this example.

Comment: You are correct. However, the error message given in my case is the titular one. An internet query would bring you here. Is there a different question on stackoverflow that you would point to? I am happy to replace this answer as a question comment pointing to another topic.

Comment: " However, the error message given in my case is the titular one." By the code shown, yes; but in this case, `foo` cannot be called a "class function" (did you mean *method*?) as there is no class to be seen anywhere. If the code is indented into a class and then used as a method, the error message will be different - getting this message *also* requires calling `foo` as a plain function namespaced within the class, in which case the author of the code has serious conceptual difficulties beyond just a typo.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, PTAL. My prior example was sufficient to generate a `NameError` for self, but was not reflective of the real world example I was describing.  My example now is aligned with a definite case. 

The reason for not defining a class prior was to highlight the fact that self is just a varible, and that a NameError just means that a variable is undefined. My example produced such an error. As in the title. 

This is the first page in some search engine results for "NameError: 'self' ...". I believe mentioning this here is important for early python learners.