# How to call a self.value in a class function definition in python?

Tags: python, class, function, self

How could I call a `self.value` in a definition of a function?

```
class toto :
    def __init__(self):
         self.titi = "titi"
    def printiti(self,titi=self.titi):
          print(titi)
```

Comment: What Python tutorial are you using?

Comment: @S.Lott: what it has to do with py3k?

Comment: This question has already been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802971/nameerror-name-self-is-not-defined/1802980#1802980 Try to search first

Comment: @SilentGhost: The syntax appears to indicate that they're using Python 3.x.  Further, comments on @gruszczy answer indicate that the syntax issue confused at least one reader.  I tried to make it clear by switching the tags.

Comment: @S.Lott: I see that, but there's nothing py3k-specific about this. OP just happens to use it.

Comment: @SilentGhost.  It may be true that it's applicable more widely. That's not my point.  My point is that someone actually was confused by an answer.   Since someone actually was confused, I stand by my suggestion to attempt to reduce the potential for confusion through an explicit tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
  def printiti(self, titi=None):
    if titi is None:
      titi = self.titi
    print titi
```

This is a common python idiom (setting default value of argument to None and checking it in method's body).

Comment: Guess what, print is a function in 3k :) Instead write: `print(titi)`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Toto:
    def __init__(self):
         self.titi = "titi"

    def printiti(self, titi=None):
         if titi is None:
             titi = self.titi
         print(titi)
```

Class names are generally Upper Case.

Comment: @Daenyth: I hate parts of PEP8.  Compliance is entirely accidental because of copy and paste from the question.  Don't thank me. Thank user462794.