# `AttributeError` while trying to access 2d list within the same class (python)

Tags: python

the code of my program is here: [Why am I getting this error "NameError:name 'self' is not defined."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665923/why-am-i-getting-this-error-nameerrorname-self-is-not-defined)

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sudoku_maker.py", line 51, in <module>
    p.main()
  File "sudoku_maker.py", line 44, in main
    self.createEasy()
  File "sudoku_maker.py", line 16, in createEasy
    if (self.puzzle[i][j] != 0):
AttributeError: 'Puzzle' object has no attribute 'puzzle'
```

The only reason I could see why this error is happening is because the list is only declared in the init function but I put it in there because I saw  another answer on here that said to do it that way. I was gonna comment on the answer saying asking how to do that for class variable but I didn't have enough rep and then I found another question where the answerer said to only declare a list in the init function.

Comment: You need to call it `self.puzzle` in `__init__` as well. This is not magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why haven't you initialised `puzzle` as an instance variable? As it is, it is only a local variable. You'll need:

```
def __init__(self, **puzzle): 
    self.puzzle = [[0 for x in range(9)]for y in range(9)]
```

`self` is your instance, and `self.x = ...` will result in `x`, an instance variable, and is accessible as an attribute of `self`.

Comment: because I didn't realize that that's how you have to write it now I think I finally fully get it. "self" is the python equivalent of the keyword "this" in a way. I wish other answer I saw about questions involving class variables explained that.

Comment: @codehelp4 Exactly. It isn't "like" `this`, it _is_ `this`. Cheers.

Comment: Having said that it still surprises me that you have to write it that what since it's the first time it's being declared. Needless to say thanks again.

Comment: @codehelp4 You don't want to declare a local variable and have it assigned as an attribute variable against your will, right? Remember, explicit is always better than implicit (Zen of Python).