# Python Self Not Defined in Default Argument for Tree Traversal

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802980/3042018) regarding the issue with using `self` in a defaultis  parameter in a Python method, but can't seem to make it work with my use case, which is a recursive call for tree traversal as shown below:

```
def in_order_traversal(self, node):
    if node != None:
        print(node, end=" ")
        self.in_order_traversal(node.left)
        self.in_order_traversal(node.right)
```

I have to call this with `tree.in_order_traversal(tree.root)` but would rather just use `tree.in_order_traversal()`, and have `node=self.root` as the second argument inf the method definition.

Can someone please suggest how to use the "workaround" given in the answer linked to?

Comment: can you show the entire class?

Comment: You don't seem to be *trying* to make it work. You don't have the default `None` value for the `node` parameter, or handle the `node is None` case.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t clear from your question, but I think your problem is that you’re already using `None` to mean “this is a leaf, nothing to print”, so you can’t *also* use `None` as a default value in the same parameter to mean “use whatever your default value is”.

The way around this is to define a “sentinel” object that isn’t `None` and also isn’t the same as any possible actual value. For example:

```
_sentinel = object()
def in_order_traversal(self, node=_sentinel):
    if node is self._sentinel:
        node = self.root
    if node != None:
        print(node, end=" ")
        self.in_order_traversal(node.left)
        self.in_order_traversal(node.right)
```

Comment: That is the issue, although since `in_order_traversal` is a class method, where can I define `_sentinel` without hitting the same problem? I.e `def in_order_traversal(self, node=self._sentinel):`

Comment: @Robin If its a class method, it should be decorated with `@classmethod` and take `cls` rather than `self` as the first parameter. If it’s an instance method—as is the case with what you posted—then just do exactly what I posted in my answer. You can’t use `self._sentinel` as a default value any more than you can use ‘self.root`, but you can use `_sentinel`, which is in scope in the class-defining namespace.