# python Testing properties defined in self

Tags: python

I am new to object-oriented programming in Python and have what seems to be a simple question and need some guidance.

If I have the following object `myclass` which is being initilized with `self` and a file path `fname`:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.title = None
        self.geo_list = []
```

Everything seems to work.

```
a = myclass('a')
```

`a` has the three properties specified in `__init__`.

But If I add a line to check to make sure `fname` is not blank or `None`:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.title = None
        self.geo_list = []

    if self.fname == '' or self.fname is None:
        raise AttributeError('Filename passed is blank.')
```

I get the NameError:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Possbile duplicate try `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802971/nameerror-name-self-is-not-defined`

Comment: You need to indent the last two lines to place them within the `__init__()` method, or else put them into a new method which has `self` as the first argument.

Comment: @tburrows13 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not a keyword in Python, it's just a plain variable name with no meaning in itself.

But there is a convention - which as far as I know is universally followed, and therefore which you should follow yourself - by which the first argument of every method in a Python class is called `self`. And this first argument is indeed a bit special, because whenever the method is called, the object itself (which is an instance of the class) is passed in as the first parameter - followed by all the other parameters that were explicitly given. So when you put `a = myclass('a')`, the `__init__` method got called with `'a'` as the second argument (which you called `fname`) and `a` itself as the first (which by convention is called `self`). [Obviously it's not quite like that because `a` isn't actually defined until the `__init__` has returned, but that's I think a reasonable way of looking at it.]

So you can only access `self` inside a method, in which `self` should always be the first argument.

Comment: For some reason I didn't realize' inside a method' means inside a function with `self`.  Thank you!

Comment: They're are used interchangeably (incorrectly) but in Python's scope a method *is* a function, but resides within an object/class (and hence makes use of self, unless for example the method is static).