# LinkedList remove() method returning NameError

Tags: python

I'm attempting to complete a practice question for school that requires us to implement a couple features into a double linked list. The `remove()` method is giving me some grief. This is what I have so far:

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.next = next

class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_node = None
        self.end_node = None

    def _find_node_(val: str):
        node = self.start_node
        while node.data != val:
            node = node.right
        return node

    #check if list empty
    def get_is_empty(self):
        if self.start_node is None:
            print("The list is empty.") #yes
        elif self.start_node is not None:
            print("The list is not empty.") #no
        else:
            print(error) #0_0

    #append item to list
    def append(self, data):
        if self.start_node is None:
            self.start_node = Entry(data)
            self.end_node = self.start_node
            return

        self.end_node.right = Entry(data)
        self.end_node = self.end_node.right
        return

    #remove given element from list
    def remove(self):
        a = input("What should be removed? ")
        if self.start_node is None:
            print("mt")
        else:
            while self.start_node.data != None:
                if self.start_node.data == a:
                    self.start_node = self.start_node.right
                elif self.start_node.data != a:
                    _find_node_()
                    self.start_node = node
                elif self.start_node.right is None:
                    print("No matching data values.")
                else:
                    print("error")

        print("Done!")

    #len of list
    def get_size(self):
        if self.start_node is None:
            print("List is empty.")

        else:
            count = 0
            x = self.start_node
            while x is not None:
                count += 1
                x = x.right
            return count

    #print all list items
    def collect(self):
        if self.start_node is None:
            print("List is empty.")

        else:
            y = self.start_node
            while y is not None:
                print(y.data)
                y = y.right

lst = DoublyLinkedList()
#lst.get_is_empty()
lst.append("i")
lst.append("a")
lst.append("e")
#lst.get_size()
lst.collect()
lst.remove()
lst.collect()
```

Results:

```
i
a
e
What should be removed? a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-185131f25d53> in <module>
     91 #lst.get_size()
     92 lst.collect()
---> 93 lst.remove()
     94 lst.collect()

<ipython-input-15-185131f25d53> in remove(self)
     50                     self.start_node = self.start_node.right
     51                 elif self.start_node.data != a:
---> 52                     _find_node_()
     53                     self.start_node = node
     54                 elif self.start_node.right is None:

NameError: name '_find_node_' is not defined
```

When I ask it to remove `i`, the first item of the list, it works flawlessly. How can I fix my error and improve my code?

Edit: When using `self._find_node_()` within `remove()`, it returns this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e15157ee586f> in <module>
     91 #lst.get_size()
     92 lst.collect()
---> 93 lst.remove()
     94 lst.collect()

<ipython-input-16-e15157ee586f> in remove(self)
     50                     self.start_node = self.start_node.right
     51                 elif self.start_node.data != a:
---> 52                     self._find_node_()
     53                     self.start_node = node
     54                 elif self.start_node.right is None:

<ipython-input-16-e15157ee586f> in _find_node_(val)
     15
     16     def _find_node_(val: str):
---> 17         node = self.start_node
     18         while node.data != val:
     19             node = node.right

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: A few things that are probably not the full problem yet: your indentation seems wrong. The functions inside the class should be indented more. And you are using `self` in the `_find_node_`, so it should take `self` as an argument. But then you need to call it as `self._find_node_()`, not just `_find_node_()`.

Comment: As @lucidbrot mentioned, all methods of a class are automatically passed the class instance — usually named `self` by convention — as their first argument. You left that out of `_find_node_()`. Also, if you're going to post question here, you'd better learn how to format them. See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `self._find_node_()` should be `self._find_node_(a)`; you're forgetting to provide the parameter you defined. Also, as was already mentioned, you have to add `self` as the first parameter of said method definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name 'self' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802971/nameerror-name-self-is-not-defined)